# How to use Liquibase parameters in db-changelog.xml for spring app

Tags: java, spring, maven, liquibase, alfresco

I have a spring application on jdk 11

**Note: The application is spring packaged as war packaging.**

using maven, with the following liquibase dependency :

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

The changelog main file is named **db.changelog.xml** , and is located under **/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/liquibase/** with the following configuration on application.properties :

```
spring.liquibase.parameters.firstname=admin1
spring.liquibase.parameters.email=admin1@abc.com
```

**Spring Version: 5.3.22**

and **db-changelog.xml** looks like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">

  <changeSet id="1" author="abc">

    <!--  USERS -->

    <createTable tableName="USER">
      <column name="login" type="varchar(50)" />
      <column name="first_name" type="varchar(50)" />
      <column name="email" type="varchar(100)" />
    </createTable>


                             
     <insert tableName="USER">
        <column name="login" value="amit"/>
        <column name="first_name" value="${firstname}"/>
        <column name="email" value="${email}"/>
    </insert></changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

When I start my tomcat server using the liquibase SQL insert the string value in the DB column as pictured below:

[image]

Can anyone please help? What I am missing here.

Comment: are you also using spring-boot or just spring? Because if only spring this won't work for you.

Comment: @bilak We are using spring and spring boot jar files but the application is packaged as a war file and deployed on an external tomcat server using Docker. Could you please help with how we can provide the values from the property file? in liquibase db-changelog.xml

Comment: Anyone, Please help as I am stuck here. Also, is there any other way to provide value from a property file in liquibase?

Comment: It seems like your application doesn't contain spring boot. Which version of spring-boot do you use? Can you try to provide some [simple application](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and store it somewhere?

Comment: @bilak Please find below the list of Spring boot Jars added to our application: 

spring-boot-2.5.12.jar
spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.12.jar
spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.5.12.jar
spring-boot-starter-2.5.12.jar
spring-boot-actuator-2.5.12.jar
spring-boot-starter-security-2.5.12.jar
spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.5.12.jar
spring-boot-starter-web-2.5.12.jar

We could not provide the actual project because of security reasons but we are using the project similar to this repo: https://github.com/OpenPj/alfresco-process-services-project-sdk/tree/2.x

Answer (score 1):

It's quite strange to see that you have the `META-INF` directory under `/WEB-INF/classes`.
Obviously this is not the location Spring Boot will look for the Liquibase changesets by default.
You'll have to configure it explicitly in your `application.properties` to make this work, something like:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:META-INF/liquibase/db.changelog.xml
```

You can add `logging.level.liquibase=debug` to you properties to log the exact locations Liquibase in reading from and queries it performs to
bring the DB to the desired state.

Comment: I Already tried adding the below properties in my application.properties file but the issue is still the same. 

spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:META-INF/liquibase/db-changelog.xml
spring.liquibase.parameters.firstname=admin
spring.liquibase.parameters.email=admin1@abc.com

My Log file reads:      INFO [main] liquibase.changelog.null ChangeSet META-INF/liquibase/db-changelog.xml::9::xxxxxxx ran successfully in 6ms

Comment: Then everything looks fine and should be working as expected. Can you share a minimal reproducible example of your issue somewhere?